# Why is axios response in camel case when sending a request in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, axios

I'm using axios with vuejs to make calls to asp.net core mvc controllers and my classes returned are all PascalCase while the response is in camelCase

I have the following class for example

```cs
 public class Department : IDepartment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name"), MaxLength(30),MinLength(2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string NameDisplay
        {
            get
            {
                return "this is a naming case test";
            }
        }

    }
```

`axios`

```js
   axios.get('Employees/GetDepartments').then(
            response => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                this.departments = response.data;
                this.departmentsLoading = false;
            }
        ).catch(e => {
            console.error('err', e);
        })
```

```
`Response Header`
```

content-type
application/json; charset=utf-8
date
Thu, 11 Jul 2019 05:41:34 GMT
server
Kestrel
X-Firefox-Spdy
h2
x-powered-by
ASP.NET
x-sourcefiles
=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcYWxpLmtc…G95ZWVzXEdldERlcGFydG1lbnRz?=

```
`Request Header`
```

Accept
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language 
en-US,ar;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control
no-cache
Connection
keep-alive
Cookie
.AspNet.Consent=yes; .AspNetCo…cxy3bpruwicbG1DYyugTJvcPNwD4w
Host
localhost:44300
Pragma
no-cache
Referer 
https://localhost:44300/employees
TE
Trailers
User-Agent
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0

````
`Response`
```json
[{"id":1,"name":"IT","nameDisplay":"this is a naming case test"},{"id":2,"name":"Research","nameDisplay":"this is a naming case test"},{"id":3,"name":"Data Entry","nameDisplay":"this is a naming case test"}]
````

Any Ideas? or am i missing something.

Comment: Do you develop with asp.net core backend and Controller? As suggestion from Dainius, this is related with `.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())` instead of axios.

Comment: @TaoZhou Thank you, out of curiosity, do you know if there is any reasons behind .net core changing the name's case to camelCase? is one of the reasons naming convensions in javascript for SPAs or re-posting the variables to controller's action etc..?